# Solr faceting date buckets

Tags: solr

I'm running a facet query for docs that have a submitted date between 2018-12-31 and 2019-11-01.  The query is running fine and I'm getting back results of the facet.  The problem is how Solr is rounding the dates for each bucket.  The buckets that are coming through are as follows:

```
"Submitted Date":{
        "counts":[
          "2018-12-31T00:00:00Z",6,
          "2019-01-31T00:00:00Z",6,
          "2019-02-28T00:00:00Z",5,
          "2019-03-28T00:00:00Z",9,
          "2019-04-28T00:00:00Z",2,
          "2019-05-28T00:00:00Z",2,
          "2019-06-28T00:00:00Z",6,
          "2019-07-28T00:00:00Z",0,
          "2019-08-28T00:00:00Z",1,
          "2019-09-28T00:00:00Z",0,
          "2019-10-28T00:00:00Z",2],
        "gap":"+1MONTH",
        "start":"2018-12-31T00:00:00Z",
        "end":"2020-11-01T00:00:00Z"
}}
```

For the most part, this is all well and good.  The problem is that the 6 documents that are placed in the `"2018-12-31T00:00:00Z"` bucket all have submitted dates that fall between 2019-01-01 and 2019-01-30.  Something similar occurs if you change the gap.start to, say, 2019-01-15.  Everything between 2019-01-15 and 2019-02-14 will be grouped together in the 2019-01-15 bucket, even those where the submitted date is in February.

Is there a way to get it so that, when working with dates, Solr groups the documents within their own month as opposed to the lower value of the range gap?  So that, using the 2019-01-15 example, only those documents between 2019-01-15 and 2019-01-31 fall into the 2019-01-15 bucket and those between 2019-02-01 and 2019-02-28 fall into the 2019-02-15 bucket?

thnx,
Christoph

Comment: Start your intervals on a proper month boundary? i.e. start it at `-01` instead of `-31`. If necessary include a second facet that retrieves the documents with `12-31`. (which the `fq` could also limit).

Comment: I guess one thing I definitely should have added in my original post is that the dates are user-driven.  The user enters a start and end date and that is used as the values for the facet range settings.  If there is no way we can specify how Solr does the grouping (which I was hoping) then we'd have to limit the user choices to start of the month only.

Comment: You can handle it in your own code, i.e. add a filter query that limits everything to `[2018-12-31T.. TO 2020-11-01T...]`, then use /MONTH for the start time (it should support date math).

Comment: @MatsLindh, could you elaborate a little bit more?  What do you mean by "use /MONTH for the start time"?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You can use date math in the start parameter - giving a date and using /MONTH will round it to the start of the month, automagically lining your bins up at the start of the month given by the user. Since you use the _actual_ month given in your `fq`, the counts in the first bin will be for what the user asked.

Comment: @MatsLindh, so it would look something like ``fq=[2018-12-31T.. TO 2020-11-01T...]/MONTH``?  Or ``fq=[2018-12-31T../MONTH TO 2020-11-01T...]``?  Can you do something similar with the facet.range.start parameter?

Comment: You'd _only_ do it in the `facet.range.start` parameter. The `fq` should not be rounded, as it'll suddenly include all of december in that case.

Comment: @MatsLindh, you've been incredibly helpful.  Thank you very much!  

So to be clear, my query would look like ``fq=[2018-12-31T.. TO 2020-11-01T...]&facet.range.start=&facet.range.start=2018-12-31T00:00:00Z/MONTH``?

Comment: Drop the duplicate `range.start` and test it :-)